# How do you pop multiple columns off a Pandas dataframe, into a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(2), 'b':range(2), 'c':range(2), 'd':range(2)})
```

I'd like to "pop" two columns ('c' and 'd') off the dataframe, into a new dataframe, leaving 'a' and 'b' behind in the original df. The following does not work:

```
df2 = df.pop(['c', 'd'])
```

Here's my error:

```
TypeError: '['c', 'd']' is an invalid key
```

Does anyone know a quick, classy solution, besides doing the following?

```
df2 = df[['c', 'd']]
df3 = df[['a', 'b']]
```

I know the above code is not *that* tedious to type, but this is why DataFrame.pop was invented--to save us a step when popping one column off a database.

Comment: I have no idea if this works, but did you try `df.pop([['c', 'd']])`?

Comment: pop returns a Series, so you can only `pop` a single column.

Comment: @ChootsMagoots, if I try what you propose, it says TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: You could do something like `pd.DataFrame([df.pop(x) for x in ['c', 'd']]).T` but I don't know if that's easier that your not-classy solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This will have to be a two step process (you *cannot* get around this, because as rightly mentioned, `pop` works for a single column and returns a Series).

First, slice `df` (step 1), and then drop those columns (step 2).

```
df2 = df[['c', 'd']].copy()
df = df.drop(['c', 'd'], axis=1)
```

And here's the one-liner version using `pd.concat`:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df.pop(x) for x in ['c', 'd']], axis=1)
```

This is still a two step process, but you're doing it in one line.

```
df

   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1

df2

   c  d
0  0  0
1  1  1
```

---

With that said, I think there's value in allowing `pop` to take a list-like of column headers appropriately returning a DataFrame of popped columns. This would make a good feature request for [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues), assuming one has the time to write one up.

Comment: Defining df and then running the command df2 = df[['c', 'd']].copy() returns error '['c', 'd']' is an invalid key. Is this answer outdated or am I missing something?

Comment: @la_leche did you do df['c', 'd'] by mistake? Or perhaps you passed a string instead of a list by accident?

Comment: Could you comment if you know the memory footprint diff between your 2 lines vs. 1 line approach. I think the one-liner IMO is more elegant (not ugly). The 2 liners may result in more human typo if # of columns is larger.

Comment: Looking at this again it's more likely the one liner is more preferable since `pop` works in place as opposed to the 2 liner method which creates multiple copies at each stop. Not benchmarked though.

Comment: I think the one-liner version is actually kind of dangerous. If you hit a key error halfway through, you are left with a frame missing some of the columns, but not all depending on where the error happens

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative, but I'm not sure if it's more classy than your original solution:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([df.pop(x) for x in ['c', 'd']]).T
df3 = pd.DataFrame([df.pop(x) for x in ['a', 'b']]).T
```

Output:

```
print(df2)
#   c  d
#0  0  0
#1  1  1

print(df3)
#   a  b
#0  0  0
#1  1  1
```

Comment: You can get around the unnecessary transposition by using `pd.concat` instead. But +1

Comment: Ah, I see with `axis=1` - that's what I was missing.

Comment: I think this solution deserves more upvotes and not sure why the website that the accepted answer was copied and pasted from calls it "ugly". The OP asked about popping multiple columns, and this answer makes it clear and explicit that this is what is happening, and does it in one line, regardless of the number of steps that are actually executed behind the scenes (after all, Python is built on C, which is built on assembly).

Answer (score 1):

new_df = old_df.loc[:,pop_columns]

Comment: This does not pop off of the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't* want to **copy** your original pd.DataFrame, using list comprehension has nice code

```
list_to_pop = ['a', 'b']
[df.pop(col) for col in list_to_pop]
```