# Move specific columns to the rightmost of the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to shift some columns in the middle of the dataframe to the rightmost.
I could do this with individual column using code:

```
cols=list(df.columns.values)
cols.pop(cols.index('one_column'))
df=df[cols +['one_column']]
df
```

But it's inefficient to do it individually when there are 100 columns of 2 series, ie. `series1_1... series1_50` and `series2_1... series2_50` in the middle of the dataframe.

How can I do it by assigning the 2 series as lists, popping them and putting them back? Maybe something like

```
cols=list(df.columns.values)
series1 = list(df.loc['series1_1':'series1_50'])
series2 = list(df.loc['series2_1':'series2_50'])
cols.pop('series1', 'series2')
df=df[cols +['series1', 'series2']]
```

but this didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to shift the columns, you could call `concat` like this:

```
cols_to_shift = ['colA', 'colB']

pd.concat([
    df[df.columns.difference(cols_to_shift)],
    df[cols_to_shift]
  ], axis=1
)
```

Or, you could do a little list manipulation on the columns.

```
cols_to_keep = [c for c in df.columns if c not in cols_to_shift]
df[cols_to_keep + cols_to_shift]
```

---

**Minimal Example**

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df

   A  B  C  D  E
0  6  1  4  4  8
1  4  6  3  5  8
2  7  9  9  2  7

cols_to_shift = ['B', 'C']
pd.concat([
    df[df.columns.difference(cols_to_shift)],
    df[cols_to_shift]
  ], axis=1
)

   A  D  E  B  C
0  6  4  8  1  4
1  4  5  8  6  3
2  7  2  7  9  9
```

```
[c for c in df.columns if c not in cols_to_shift] 
df[cols_to_keep + cols_to_shift]

   A  D  E  B  C
0  6  4  8  1  4
1  4  5  8  6  3
2  7  2  7  9  9
```

Comment: Thanks @cs95 it returned   `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when I assigned `cols_to_shift = ['series1_1':'series1_50']`

Comment: @nilsinelabore Lot to unpack there but the crux of it is you cannot use this syntax outside of `pandas.loc`. If you want to specify a range of columns, you'll want to do something like `cols_to_shift = df.loc['series1_1':'series1_50'].columns.tolist()` OR `cols_to_shift = [*df.loc['series1_1':'series1_50']]` and then try doing whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: can I use something similar to `cols.pop(cols_to_shift)` to put the series of columns back? But it returned `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. I did this `cols_to_shift = df.loc['series1_1':'series1_50'].columns.tolist()`

Comment: @nilsinelabore Clearly you can't pop more than one column at a time, otherwise the code in your question would have worked. See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329569/how-do-you-pop-multiple-columns-off-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-new-dataframe/49329633#49329633, and I would recommend you try one of the suggested solutions first, then ask questions after.

Answer (score 0):

I think list.pop only takes indices of the elements in the list.
You should list.remove instead.

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
for s in (‘series1’, ‘series2’):
    cols.remove(s)
df = df[cols + [‘series1’, ‘series2’]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Kazuya it returned `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` as I assigned `series1 = list(['series1_1':'series1_50'])`